# Create columns based on count in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I have a data as below:

```
Col1  Col2   Col3  Col4 
1     7000     73     6  
1     7000     73     7   
1     7000     73     8   
1     7000     73     9   
1     7000     73    10   
1     7000     73    11   
1     7000     73    12   
1     4000    117     6 
1     4000    117     9
```

I want to count the number by `Col1` and `Col2`. And then, based on the count to create 5 new columns. I know how to count but how can I create 5 new columns based on the count.

```
Col1  Col2   Count   NewCol1  NewCol2  NewCol3  NewCol4  NewCol5  
1     7000       7         6        7        8        9       10  
1     4000       2         6        9        NA      NA       NA
```

`Col3` can be ignored actually.

There is one thing that `Count` ranges from 1 to more than 5. Therefore, if `Count > 5`, I do not need to have `NewCol6`, `NewCol7`, and etc.

Comment: This is the simple example I randomly create. In real data, there will be more than 5 under the same `Col1` and `Col2`. But if it is more than 5, I do not need `NewCol6`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a frequency column with 'add_count', grouped by 'Col1', 'Col2', then create a sequence naming column ('nm1'), use `complete` to expand the data for missing combinations and reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    add_count(Col1, Col2) %>% 
    group_by(Col1, Col2) %>%
    slice(seq_len(5)) %>%
    mutate(nm1 = str_c("NewCol", row_number())) %>% 
    complete(nm1 = str_c("NewCol", 1:5)) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    dplyr::select(-Col3) %>% 
    fill(n) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = nm1, values_from = Col4)
# A tibble: 2 x 8
#   Col1  Col2     n NewCol1 NewCol2 NewCol3 NewCol4 NewCol5
#  <int> <int> <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#1     1  4000     1       6      NA      NA      NA      NA
#2     1  7000     2       6       7      NA      NA      NA
```

---

With the second dataset

```
df2 %>%
        add_count(Col1, Col2) %>% 
        group_by(Col1, Col2) %>%
        slice(seq_len(5)) %>%
        mutate(nm1 = str_c("NewCol", row_number())) %>% 
        complete(nm1 = str_c("NewCol", 1:5)) %>%
        ungroup %>% 
        dplyr::select(-Col3) %>% 
        fill(n) %>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = nm1, values_from = Col4)
# A tibble: 2 x 8
#   Col1  Col2     n NewCol1 NewCol2 NewCol3 NewCol4 NewCol5
#  <int> <int> <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#1     1  4000     2       6       9      NA      NA      NA
#2     1  7000     7       6       7       8       9      10
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df2)[, n  := .N, .(Col1, Col2)][,
   head(.SD, 5), .(Col1, Col2)], Col1 + Col2 + n ~  
  factor(paste0("NewCol", rowid(Col1, Col2)), 
       levels = paste0("NewCol", 1:5)), value.var = 'Col4')
#   Col1 Col2 n NewCol1 NewCol2 NewCol3 NewCol4 NewCol5
#1:    1 4000 2       6       9      NA      NA      NA
#2:    1 7000 7       6       7       8       9      10
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Col2 = c(7000L, 7000L, 4000L
), Col3 = c(73L, 73L, 117L), Col4 = c(6L, 7L, 6L)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    Col2 = c(7000L, 7000L, 7000L, 7000L, 7000L, 7000L, 7000L, 
    4000L, 4000L), Col3 = c(73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 
    117L, 117L), Col4 = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 
    9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: I tried the code on my data, but it shows `NewCol6`, `NewCol7`, .... Moreover, it is time consuming.

Comment: `unique(dt[, .N, .(Col1, Col2)]$N) >>  [1]  1  2  3  4  6 10  5  8 22  7 11 12`. The max value is *22*.

Comment: No. `Col3` is useless.

Comment: I updated the example to make it count more than 5.

Comment: Yes, it works and gets the right. However, it is time consuming. Is there any `data.table` way to manipulate? or it will not improve processing time with `data.table`?

Comment: @PeterChen UPdated the post with `data.table`

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option:

```
DT[, as.list(head(c(Col4, rep(NA_real_, 5L)), 5L)), .(Col1, Col2)]
```

output:

```
   Col1 Col2 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1:    1 7000  6  7  8  9 10
2:    1 4000  6  9 NA NA NA
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Col1  Col2   Col3  Col4 
1     7000     73     6  
1     7000     73     7   
1     7000     73     8   
1     7000     73     9   
1     7000     73    10   
1     7000     73    11   
1     7000     73    12   
1     4000    117     6 
1     4000    117     9")
```